# using different borders on all sides of td

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is it possible with css3 to apply borders on `table, tr, td` so it would look like it is drawn by hand similar to:

[image]

---

Currently, I'm trying like the following but which results in space between tds:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
td{
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojaEj.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

So, is there a way so I can use different borders on top right bottom and left of the tds?

Comment: That is going to be really really difficult to achieve with CSS. I would suggest using some other alternates (but adding CSS-Shapes tag just in case anybody can help you).

Comment: Theoretically, you can generate images for border-image of each cell, but I've never heard of anyone who did this to simulate hand drawing.

Comment: @Klaster_1 Exactly what I was thinking. I was trying to write up an answer but it's quite difficult to implement, let alone explain it. Another option would be to slice the image into cells and set a different background for every table cell (SVG would be a better choice here though)

Comment: Your edit has spaces because the image you are using has spaces, and you are applying it to each table cell. You can't overlap table cells so that won't work.

Comment: @willoer yes, there is space in image as image is not straight line border but it's curve so it obviously get some space around there.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that by carefully crafting a table with no borders or background (so it's transparent) and using your hand-drawn graphic as a background.

If you design the background to be repeating (seamless) your table could even be dynamic.

```
table {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/idN4k.jpg) -10px -15px repeat;
}
table td {
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="37">one</td>
    <td width="42">two</td>
    <td width="42">three</td>
    <td width="42">four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nhur0uu0/

This could also be achieved with custom svg, but I would want to know more about what you are going for before I recommended it.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's quite hard to match the image cell with every table cell. If every cell is equally large, this could be an option though.

Comment: Yeah you will have to be careful to keep your drawing pretty close to straight rows and columns. A little deviation though will make a cool effect. You might also have to customize some column widths and row heights to keep it looking good.

Comment: I'd definitely go for SVG's in this case. You don't want your borders to look fuzzy or aliased.

Comment: I added a fiddle using the same graphic as in the OP.

Comment: True! The simplest version of this is a fixed layout.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve something like that with [border-images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) and applying different border images to every Nth cell with the [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selectors on both rows and columns, maybe with some prime numbers thrown in to obscure repetition.

This will require `border-collapse:separate` tables, so you'll also want zero border spacing.

The images will have to line up properly at the corners though, so the lines can't be quite as crooked as in your example

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting negative margins as I did here.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojaEj.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: -9px -8px;
    display: inline-block;
}
tr {
    display: block;
}
tr:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left:4px;
}
tr:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left:8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Not too pretty, but it works.